# How to hyperlink the 'general index' in the resulting PDF without it appearing in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdftex, indexing, books

I want my book (in PDF file) have an 'Contents' (general index) hyperlinked. But do not want the line of the word 'contents' (including page number) in the content of the table of contents, redundant to appear. To be exact: What would you change my tex file I put down here? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{General Index}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{section one}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

P.D. I put here a screenshot image of my PDF file describing what I look even better.[image]

Comment: My image capture even better describes what I need to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{General Index}
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{TOC}{}
\bookmark[level=0, dest=TOC]{General Index}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{section one}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that was just what I needed, thank you very much :)

Comment: @mathsalomon -- Glad it's what you're after!