# add hyperindex of phantom sections to final PDF when merging multiple PDFs

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdfpages

I'm merging some PDFs using `pdfpages` and I would like to add some phantom bookmarks to make a *clickable* table of context on the side of my final PDF (I imagine using hyperref), a bit [like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106112/22939) or [like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154517/22939). I've tried adding `\section{section one}`, etc., but I still don't get the usual interactive table of content in my final PDF. I also tried looking in [pdfpages manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf), but until now with no luck. Can someone here help me solve this?

Code (you need some random `file_01.pdf` and `file_02.pdf`),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\includepdf[pages=1-7]{file_01.pdf}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\includepdf[pages=8-]{file_01.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{file_02.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have any indication that this is supported by the package? From `pdfpages.pdf`: *When including pages of a PDF only the so called content stream of these pages is copied but no links. [...] Some links may be extracted and later reinserted by a package called pax which can be downloaded from CTAN.* Have you checked out `pax`?

Comment: Hadn't seen that, thanks! However, it [seems as `pax`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pax) is a program intended for _preserving_ an­no­ta­tions across merges. I want to add my own (new) bookmarks/phantom sections to the merged PDF.

Answer (score 4):

`\includepdf` has option `pagecommand`, which can be used to insert an entry for the table of contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{roman}
\includepdf[
  pages=1,
  pagecommand=\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{File 01, Page 1},
]{file_01.pdf}
\includepdf[
  pages=2,
  pagecommand=\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{File 02, Page 2},
]{file_01.pdf}
\end{document}
```

`\phantomsection` creates an anchor for the following `\addcontentsline`.
`hyperref` catches `\addcontentsline` for the bookmarks.

If the precise location for the link target inside the included pages is needed, then the `\phantomsection` can be placed via environment `picture` (with size zero).

Alternatively the link targets of the included PDF files can be imported via PAX. If bookmarks are needed only, they can then be set via package `bookmark`, even outside of `pagecommand`.

Comment: Thanks! Would you have time to demonstrate the _`picture` (with size zero) environment_? My PDFs `file_01.pdf` and `file_02.pdf` is 50 and 53 pages respectively and I hope to add 3 or 4 sections to each.  I see you used `pages=1` and  `pages=2` for the two files (I take my initial post gave the impression that I am merging two pages from two PDFs).

Comment: @EricFail Sorry, I do not understand the comment.